# Is there a way to trigger hover behavior in the Chrome Beta browser?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Is there any way to trigger the behavior that usually occurs when a mouse is hovered over an element (for example, hovering over your username at the top of a Stack Overflow site) using the Chrome Beta browser?

Comment: This doesn't help in the general case, but specifically for your name at the top of StackOverflow sites, you can tap the little down arrow beside your name to trigger the same behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to trigger the hover on links is to long-press the link, wait for the menu to appear, and the press the back button to cancel the menu. This also works in some other browsers.

Note that this doesn't work on all links. Just tried on the example you mentioned, doesn't work, probably because there's a slight delay between the onMouseOver event and showing the menu. But on other pages, where it's a simple onMouseOver trigger this method works.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a device (usually a tablet) with a USB port, you can plug in a mouse.

The mouse cursor will trigger hover events.

Comment: Or a wireless mouse via Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the "hover" effect can be practical on any touchscreen device, regardless of OS.

Screens on most current mobile devices (resistive, capacitive) can only register touch events.  You would need to modify the OS to treat a single tap as a mouse pointer, and double-tap as a "click".  However other gestures like scrolling, pinch-to-zoom, etc. would most likely stop working with such a paradigm.

Also, most mobile versions of sites disable the fancy stuff like hover animations anyways, in order to load faster.

Comment: I'm finding Chrome on my tablet (Asus Transformer Prime) to be nearly as functional as a laptop; in most cases, I would not choose to use a mobile version of a site.   I think this will be an interesting issue for designers to grapple with -- things like tooltips and the StackOverflow user card are not available to touchscreen users, which is more of an issue for the ux site, but I was curious if Chrome had found some general way to expose this in the touch environment.

Comment: This is nonsense (or at least a lack of imagination). It's easy to imagine something like a browser interpreting a two finger tap as "hover here until I tap somewhere else". This would let mobile and tablet users get proper use of those few websites that haven't gone with the times and still rely on hovering behavior.

Comment: My phone (Galaxy Note 3) can sense when your finger is near the screen. In the stock browser it shows a zoomed window. This would be perfect for hover but does not currently work in any other browser AFAIK.