# How can I hover over some text on a webpage in Opera for Android?

Tags: android-12, google-pixel-6, opera-browser

On [this Timeline on Patents.SE](https://patents.stackexchange.com/posts/24959/timeline), for example, hovering over the `S` shows it stands for "simultaneous dates" (see image below).
This works on Chrome desktop, but not on Opera mobile.

[image: screenshot showing the mouse hover popup]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to trigger hover behavior in the Chrome Beta browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20122/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-hover-behavior-in-the-chrome-beta-browser)